# Default select value AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

View:

```
 <select class="medium validate[required]" ng-model="dept" ng-options="dept.name for dept in agentdepart">
       <option value="">---Choose Department---</option>
 </select>
```

Model:

```
 $http.get('/admin-data?id='+$rootScope.adminid).success(function(data)
      {

$scope.mailid=data.mailid;

$scope.dept='data.department.name';
          });
```

how my select list will appear with default value ?

Comment: if the `ng-model` is `null`, the default `<option>` will be shown.

Comment: Yes its correct i am asking about default value if i change <option value="defaultvalue"></option> its not work

Comment: Why not use `null` for the view and then map to a default value in the controller?

Comment: If i set $scope.dept='defaultvalue' in controller this value means this text not appear in select box

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to "pre-populate" with a value that is in the `agentdepart` array?

Comment: Yes i want to receive value from server and then display in option but the select box will appear default value